# Easy C Program Error

Tags: c, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, compiler-errors

im writing a very simple program to display mock weather data for a class and i cant figure out why visual studio keeps giving me an error

the error is on temperature through direction its telling me: error C2440: '=' : cannot convert from 'double (__cdecl *)(void)' to 'double'

im lost please help

```
void DisplayWeatherData(void)
{
    double temperature,humidity,pressure,windspeed,direction,bt,bp,bw;

    temperature = GetTemperature;
    humidity = GetHumidity;
    pressure = GetPressure;
    windspeed = GetWindspeed;
    direction = GetWindDirection;
    bt = (temperature * 9.0 / 5.0) + 32.0;
    bp = pressure * KPATOINHG;
    bw = windspeed * KMTOMPH;


    printf("\nTemperature: %4.1lf C\tHumidity: %3.0lf%%\tPressure: %4.1lf kPa\n",temperature,humidity,pressure);
    printf("Windspeed: %3.0lf km/hr\tDirection: %3.0lf Degrees\n\n",windspeed,direction);

    printf("\nTemperature: %4.1lf F\tHumidity: %3.0lf%%\tPressure: %4.1lf inHg\n",bt,humidity,bp);
    printf("Windspeed: %3.0lf mph\tDirection: %3.0lf Degrees\n\n",bw,direction);


}

double GetTemperature(void)
{
return 25.1;
}
double GetHumidity(void)
{
return 55.4;
}   
double GetPressure(void)
{
return 101.7;
}   
double GetWindspeed(void)
{
return 15.5;
}   
double GetWindDirection(void)
{
return 320.0;
}
```

Comment: Simple typo errors.`GetTemperature` --> `GetTemperature()`

Comment: `temperature = GetTemperature;` --> `temperature = GetTemperature();` and so on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You missed parenthesis at this:

```
temperature = GetTemperatur;
humidity = GetHumidity;
pressure = GetPressure;
windspeed = GetWindspeed;
direction = GetWindDirection;
```

It should be like:

```
temperature = GetTemperature();
.//same
.//same
.//same
direction = GetWindDirection();
```